# Trying to select the filepath without declaring it in string

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to make it so when i click my button I can chose which .txt file i want to select and than get the Lines Count displayed on my label

```
string filePath = "C:\\Users\\Ristic\\Desktop\\Neki.txt";
int count = System.IO.File.ReadLines(filePath).Count();
string a = count.ToString();
label1.Text = a;
```

Comment: And what's a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use OpenFileDialog here.

For example,

```
var openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog()
{
    DefaultExt = "txt",  
    Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt",  
}
openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)  
{  
     filePath  = openFileDialog1.FileName;  
}
```

The OpenFileDialog.Filter property allows you to filter the files by extension, which in your case is ".txt".

You can read more on OpenFileDialog [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog?view=netframework-4.7.2)